# Customize loading template for non-nested ember route

Tags: ember.js

Using ember: 1.7.0

I'm trying to used different loading templates depending on the route that is being transitioned to in my app.  None of my routes are nested (i.e. contained within a resource).  I've only been able to get ember to serve up the application `loading` template.  Is there a way to override this behavior in the case of non-nested routes?

Here's a jsbin illustration the problem:

1. Two loading templates are defined `loading` and `top-loading`.
2. When loaded up the app transitions to the `top` route.
3. I was hoping this would trigger the `top-loading` template, but instead it triggers the `loading` template.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pamego/1/

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to do that thing where I question a premise of your question:

If your routes aren't nested then there should be no harm in treating them as resources. Routes only have special behavior when they are nested (they don't reset their namespace).

Conceptually, changing this route to a resource works. The "loading" state is really an enhancement or a special form of "top". When something has multiple states like this, modeling it as a resource makes sense. With all that preamble, I propose this:

http://jsbin.com/javihuceqo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your route is only nested one level deep, so the application-level loading substate is active.  If you had a `Route` that was 2 levels down, "`FooBar`", for example, then trying to load the `FooBarRoute` model would cause the `foo/loading` template to be displayed.

Please see [this jsbin for an example](http://jsbin.com/nahaqisite/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You're actually both right, but I don't want to clutter up the URL with another level.  Thanks again!